# Error while Debugging using Eclipse for DS-5

Tags: eclipse, arm, ds-5

I am using DS5 evaluation version. I created a simple hello world C project in eclipse for DS5. Project type chosen while creating the project is Bare Metal executable->Empty project. Tool chains ARM Compiler 5 was selected. I complied the code and generated the axf file. When i right click on the axf file and select debug as->debug configurations->Connection tab->ARM FVP VE_Cortex_A7x1->Bare Metal Debug->Debug Cortex-A7 and click on debug I am facing the error as in the image.

Please let me know how to resolve the same.

[image]

Comment: Further to the above information, the same hello world project works for Cortex A8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing that error is that the evaluation version of DS-5 Professional Edition gives you access to the Cortex-A8 and Cortex-A9 FVPs, not the Cortex-A7 one.

Extra FVPs need to be purchased separately from ARM.